# Is my GD library turned on or not?

Tags: php

Is my GD library turned on or not? I am using Windows 7, Xampp and Chrome.

```
<?php gd_info();?>
```

there is nothing displayed

**php.ini**

```
extension=php_gd2.dll  // not commented
```

The error log does not contain any errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `gd_info()` returns an array, this will show what you want to see

```
$a = gd_info();
echo '<pre>' . print_r($a,1) . '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 2):

You have not printed the array. `gd_info()` returns an associative array. So try this:

```
<?php print_r(gd_info()); ?>
```

[Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gd-info.php).